# Why "state Vuex" is not saved after "dispatch action" in middleware

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I load cookie "darkMode" to Vuex in middleware

Store index.js

```js
    import * as mut from './mutation-map'

    export const state = () => ({
      darkMode: false
    })

    export const getters = () => ({
      darkMode: state => state.darkMode
    })

    export const mutations = {
      [mut.SET__DARK_MODE]: (state, mode) => {
        console.log('mutated', mode)
        state.darkMode = mode
      }
    }

    export const actions = {
      toggleDarkMode({ commit, state }, mode) {
        commit(mut.SET__DARK_MODE, mode)
      }
    }
```

middleware cookie.js

```js
    export default function(ctx) {
      ctx.store.dispatch('toggleDarkMode', ctx.app.$cookies.get('darkMode'))
    }
```

This works fine on the server, but on the client, the Vuex state remains the default!

Does Vue middleware only work on the server? I have previously loaded a session from a Cookie in Vuex in this way, but this does not work for me with the latest update

Comment: are u sure that ctx.app.$cookies.get('darkMode') on client return what u need?